# Are there achievements available in one version of Minecraft BE that aren't available in another?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, ios, version-differences, windows-10

I own [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) on [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one), [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios). I like having the flexibility of being able to transition between the three platforms and take my creative worlds on the go through my Realms subscription. However, I recently began playing Minecraft in survival mode and that journey began on the XBOX One version of the game.

I earned many achievements during my first day of survival and some of them were for very basic things such as:

- Opening the Inventory
- Making a Crafting Table
- Creating a Pickaxe
- Crafting a *Better* Pickaxe

Subsequently, when I started playing in survival on my phone last night, I earned those same achievements a second time, netting myself an additional 55 gamerscore:

[image: Screenshot of all three titles in the achievements pane on Windows 10.]

This made me curious however...

---

Although it doesn't *appear* that way at a glance due to matching available gamerscores, are there achievements available in one version of Minecraft that aren't available in another? For example, are there achievements available in the [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) version that aren't available in the [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one) version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, there are no achievements that are specific to a device for [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).

---

This is true, no matter the device you're playing on (see the [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition) tag for a full list of compatible devices). Per the [fandom wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Achievement), there is a single list of achievements:

> There are 114 achievements in Bedrock Edition...

While there is nothing explicitly stating that there **are not** any achievements specific to device types, there is also nothing explicitly stating that there are, which leads to the inference that there is a singular list of achievements.

After a grueling hour and a half of cross-comparing the achievements between [xbox-one](/questions/tagged/xbox-one), [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) versions of the game in the XBOX app, I can say with 99% confidence that the answer is no, all achievements have the same score, title, and description, across all versions.

---

<sub>***Note**: See the aforementioned fandom wiki for a complete list of achievements available in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition).*</sub>